# React-native encoding barcode

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode, cordova-plugins, react-native

I'm using the phonegap-barcode plugin in react-native thanks to : https://github.com/axemclion/react-native-cordova-plugin.

I have been able to scan a barcode and get it's data but now I'm trying to generate a barcode and I have a problem.

When I'm calling my function :

```
cordova.cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.encode(
  cordova.cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.format.ean_13,
  barcodeValue,
  function() {console.log('success')},
  function() {console.log('failed')}
```

)}

I have this message : "Could not encode a barcode from the data provided".

If I put :

```
cordova.cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.encode(
  cordova.cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE,
  "test",
  function() {console.log('success')},
  function() {console.log('failed')}
```

)}

This code generate a qr_code but that's not what I want, I want a barcode.

I remenber that in android I was using the multiformatwriter class to generate my bitmap.

So is it possible to generate a barcode image or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, awesome... Good job so far.

Based on [the docs](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/blob/master/README.md), I wouldn't expect your first example to work. The second looks solid though.

I think you'll probably get the answer your after from the issue you filled more than likely since they will know best whether it can produce a barcode
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/96